# Swift - sorting tableview data by date only sorting cells within initial view

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a UITableView with 100 data elements added to it. The data is generated with the following method:

```
    func generateMockAPIResponse(generate numberRecordsToGenerate: Int) -> [CellData] {
        
        var data: [CellData] = []
        let type = ["PreCount", "PostCount"]
        let location = ["BBS", "LHR", "CDG", "CCF"]
        
        for _ in 1...numberRecordsToGenerate {
            let date = Date().changed(day: -Int.random(in: 0...60)) ?? Date()
            let preTotal = Double.random(in: 500..<1000)
            let postTotal = Double.random(in: 10000..<50000)
            let difference = postTotal - preTotal
            data.append(
                CellData(
                    type: type[Int.random(in: 0..<type.count)],
                    date: date,
                    id: "AG\(String(Int.random(in: 100..<900)))",
                    preTotal: preFuel,
                    postTotal: postFuel,
                    difference: uplift,
                    dur: Double.random(in: 0.80...0.85),
                    location: location[Int.random(in: 0..<location.count)]))
        }
        return data
    }
```

Essentially I'm generating a mock API response here. And I call this method in viewDidLoad:

```
var data = [CellData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // To be removed once API is in place
    data = sortAndConvertData(data: generateMockAPIResponse(generate: 100))            
}
```

Then I have a sortAndConvert function:

```
    private func sortAndConvertData(data: [CellData]) -> [CellData] {
        var convertedData: [CellData] = []
        
        for data in data {
            if let preTotal = data.preTotal,
                let postTotal = data.postTotal,
                let difference = data.difference,
                let dur = data.dur,
                
                let convertedPreTotal = // code converts to difference unit of measure,
                let convertedPostTotal = // code converts to difference unit of measure,
                let convertedDifference = // code converts to difference unit of measure,
                let convertedDur = // code converts to difference unit of measure
            {
                
                convertedData.append(
                    CellData(
                        type: data.type,
                        date: data.date,
                        id: data.flightNumber,
                        preTotal: convertedPreFuel,
                        postTotal: convertedPostFuel,
                        difference: convertedUplift,
                        dur: convertedDensity,
                        location: data.location
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        return convertedData.sorted(by: { $0.date?.compare($1.date ?? Date()) == .orderedDescending })
    }
}
```

So the data I end up with should be sorted by date. Then I declare my cells as follows:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell: HistoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeue(indexPath: indexPath)
        cell.data = data[indexPath.row]

        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.i6.alternateTableCells : .white
        
        return cell
    }
```

So this all works for all the cells within the table view. However, when user scrolls the order becomes jumbled as a result of the dequeueing process. How do I avoid the order being destroyed by reusable cells?

EDIT:

Setting data in custom cell:

```
   private func populateData() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yy"
        
        if let dataDate = data?.date,
            let dataPreTotal = data?.preFuel,
            let dataPostTotal = data?.postFuel,
            let dataDifference = data?.uplift,
            let dataDur = data?.density
        {
            typeLabel.text = data?.type
            date.valueLabel.text = formatter.string(from:dataDate)
            id.valueLabel.text = data?.id
            preTotal.valueLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", dataPrefuel)
            postTotal.valueLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", dataPostFuel)
            difference.valueLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", dataUplift)
            dur.valueLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", dataDensity)
            location.valueLabel.text = data?.location
        }
    }
```

This is called in:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    populateData()
    configureAutoLayout()
}
```

Comment: The code is not relevant. The relevant code is the `didSet` observer of `data` in the custom cell

Comment: I just added where I set these values in the custom cell class

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to resolve this. The issue was that I was calling the populateData() method within the custom cell class with didMoveToSuperView()

I have now set this to the didSet() method of the data object in the custom cell class:

```
    var data: FuelHistoryTableViewController.CellData? {
    didSet {
        populateData()
    }
}
```